# Github workflows dependancy, sequential order

Tags: github, github-actions, devops, cicd

Pylint workflow

```
name: Pylint

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - sprint-1-be  # Change this to the branch you want to monitor

jobs:
  check_files:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      py_exists: ${{ steps.check_py.outputs.py_exists }}
      req_exists: ${{ steps.check_req.outputs.req_exists }}
    steps:
      - name: Check out code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Check for Python files
        id: check_py
        run: |
          if find . -name "*.py" | grep -q .; then
            echo "::set-output name=py_exists::true"
          else
            echo "No Python files found. Skipping."
            echo "::set-output name=py_exists::false"
          fi

      - name: Check for requirements.txt
        id: check_req
        if: steps.check_py.outputs.py_exists == 'true'
        run: |
          if [ ! -f requirements.txt ]; then
            echo "::error::No requirements.txt found. Failing the action."
            exit 1
          else
            echo "::set-output name=req_exists::true"
          fi

  linting:
    needs: check_files
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: needs.check_files.outputs.py_exists == 'true' && needs.check_files.outputs.req_exists == 'true'
    steps:
      - name: Check out code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: 3.11

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install -r requirements.txt
          pip install pylint

      - name: Run Pylint
        run: |
          pylint_score=9  # Change this to the minimum required score
          fail=false

          for file in $(find . -name "*.py" -type f); do
            score=$(pylint "$file" | grep -oP '(?<=Your code has been rated at ).*(?=/10)')
            echo "Pylint score for $file: $score/10"
            if (( $(bc <<< "$score < $pylint_score") )); then
              echo "Pylint score for $file is less than $pylint_score."
              fail=true
            fi
          done

          if [ "$fail" = true ]; then
            echo "Pylint check failed."
            exit 1
          else
            echo "Pylint check passed."
          fi
```

CI/CD workflow

```
name: CI/CD Pipeline Docker

on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ["Pylint"]
    types:
      - completed #dependency of pylint workflow, if pylint workflows passes, then CI/CD pipeline starts

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Clean up workspace
        run: |
          rm -rf ./*

      - name: Set up SSH key and directory
        run: |
          mkdir -p ~/.ssh
          echo "${{ secrets.SERVER_SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}" > ~/.ssh/private_key
          chmod 600 ~/.ssh/private_key
        env:
          SSH_PRIVATE_KEY: ${{ secrets.SERVER_SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}

      - name: Check Github User
        run: |
          git --version
          git config --global user.username "abdullah-zia-22"
          git config --global user.email "sipra58@gmail.com"
          git config user.username
          git config user.email
          
      - name: Deploy to EC2 via SSH
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.EC2_HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.SSH_USERNAME }}
          key: ${{ secrets.SERVER_SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
          port: ${{ secrets.SSH_PORT }}
          script: |    
            # Navigate to the directory where your app will reside
            cd /var/www/backend/

            # Pull the latest code from the current repository
            git config --global user.username "abdullah-zia-22"
            git config --global user.email "sipra58@gmail.com"

            #dynamic repo name
            folder_name=$(basename ${{ github.repository }})
            echo "Folder name is: $folder_name"

            #repo configuration
            sudo rm -rf /var/www/backend/$folder_name
            cd /var/www/backend/
            sudo chmod 777 /var/www/backend
            repo_url="https://${{ secrets.GH_TOKEN }}@github.com/${{ github.repository }}.git"
            echo "repo url is: $repo_url"
            git remote set-url origin $repo_url
            git clone $repo_url

            # Pull the latest code from the current repository
            echo "Folder path is: /var/www/backend/$folder_name"
            cd /var/www/backend/$folder_name
            git checkout sprint-1-be
            image_name="${folder_name//-/_}_api"
            sudo docker stop $image_name 
            sudo docker rm $image_name -f 
            sudo docker rmi $image_name -f
            sudo docker build -f /var/www/backend/$folder_name/Dockerfile \
            --build-arg mysqlhost=${{ secrets.MYSQLHOST }} \
            --build-arg mysqldatabasename=${{ secrets.MYSQLDATABASENAME }} \
            --build-arg mysqluser=${{ secrets.MYSQLUSER }} \
            --build-arg mysqlpassword=${{ secrets.MYSQLPASSWORD }} \
            --build-arg mysqlcharset=${{ secrets.MYSQLCHARSET }} \
            --build-arg mysqlport=${{ secrets.MYSQLPORT }} \
            -t $image_name .
            sudo docker run -d --name $image_name -p ${{ secrets.DEPLOY_PORT }}:5000 $image_name &&
            sudo systemctl reload nginx

            sudo firewall-cmd --add-port ${{ secrets.DEPLOY_PORT }}/tcp
```

I want to execute ci/cd workflow after successful execution of pylint workflow.
pylint workflow executes successfully. Whenever code is pushed, pylint workflow executes but ci cd workflow doesn't trigger even if pylint workflow passes.
I have searched articles and blogs. Found same solution as above but it's not working.

Comment: "CI/CD Pipeline Docker" ([`workflow_run`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_run)) should be on the default branch.

Comment: but i want to enable ci cd on different branch

Comment: But, currently, that's the limitation. You can work around that. You can create a [reusable workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows) and call that after your linting job is complete.

Comment: can you please provide me syntax or link or something. I'm new to devOps. Thanks for replying btw

Comment: Links are already added in the above comments. Please follow the [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/about-workflows), experiment, and you'll figure it out. Good luck! You're welcome to post questions if you don't find any answers in the previous threads.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way to do it. I changed CI/CD action to `workflow_dispatch` so that I can trigger it manually. `workflow_run` only works for the default branch. After completion of the pylint workflow, I simply curl the CI/CD workflow, and it starts running.

[curl command](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/workflow-runs?apiVersion=2022-11-28)

Comment: This is a good start to an answer. But to make it complete, can you [edit] your answer to include an example of the Curl command so it's not dependent on a link to address that part of your solution?